# How to fetch Unique ID of particular Row in jQuery Datatable to Delete it with Laravel Backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables

I was using Laravel API and jQuery Datatable to display some data fetched from MySQL Database.
I somehow figured how to display Edit and Delete buttons in my datatable but cannot figure how to pass unique ID to the backend in order to Edit or Delete that record.

My Datatable code is below

```
let table = $('#table').DataTable({
        ajax: "/tests",
        paging: false,
        scrollY: 400,
        language: {
            info: "Fetched _MAX_ Results. Displaying _MAX_",
        },
        order: ['0', 'desc'],
        ordering: true,
        searching: true,

        columns: [
            {data: "id"},
            {data: "name"},
            {data: "email"},
            {data: "bio"},
            {data: "child"},
            {data: "created_at"},
            {data: "updated_at"},
            {
                data: null,
                defaultContent: "<button class='btn btn-sm btn-info' id='editUser' style='color: #fff;'>Edit</button>",
            },
            {
                data: null,
                defaultContent: "<button class='btn btn-sm btn-danger' id='deleteUser'>Delete</button>",
            }
        ],
```

I want to somehow pass the ID into the Edit and Delete buttons so that I can use that a Edit or Delete the record from my Database using Laravel.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Hey @Steal1702 Please check this document `https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/inTableControls.html` that will help you.

Comment: Note you can't repeat ID's in a page, they are unique by definition

Comment: https://w3path.com/laravel-6-ajax-crud-tutorial-using-datatables-from-scratch/